# Verilog 'cannot match operand(s)' & 'multiple constant drivers'

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm working on a Verilog project using a FPGA (BEMICROMAX10) and some breadboard components. The project is to make a digital clock in which you can also set the time using the buttons on the FPGA. I realize this Verilog code is not the most efficient way to write this but it's how I currently have it set up.

The time from seconds to minutes to hours, is working perfectly when I power it but I can not get the buttons to function to change the minutes and hours manually (while the seconds are running). If you look at line 98 after the large chunk of seconds, I run into the error when I add 'or posedge outm'. I've tried other things but it seems I either get the 'cannot match operands' error or the 'multiple constant drivers' error which I assume is telling me I'm trying to change countmin and counthr with multiple inputs (from clk and btn). I'm really stuck and have no idea where to go from here.

I've just made an edit to drive slow_clk2 with another clock input on the FPGA, and added the outm line for the button, but still no luck.

```
module digital_clock(clk, clk2, minbtn, hrbtn, segsec, segmin, seghr);
input clk, clk2, minbtn, hrbtn;
output [13:0] segsec;
output [13:0] segmin;
output [13:0] seghr;

parameter N = 25;
reg [N-1:0] slow_clk = 0;
reg [7:0] countsec = 0, countmin = 0, counthr = 8'h1;

parameter M = 13;
reg [M-1:0] slow_clk2 = 0;
reg [7:0] delay = 0;
reg [7:0] delay2 = 0;
wire outm, outh;

always @ (posedge clk)
    slow_clk <= slow_clk + 1'b1;

always @ (posedge clk2)
    slow_clk2 <= slow_clk2 + 1;

always @ (posedge slow_clk2[M-1])
    begin
    delay <= delay << 1;    
    delay2 <= delay2 << 1;
    delay[0] <= ~minbtn;
    delay2[0] <= ~hrbtn;
    end

assign outm = delay[7] & delay[6] & delay[5] & delay[4] & delay[3] & delay[2] & delay[1] & delay[0];

assign outh = delay2[7] & delay2[6] & delay2[5] & delay2[4] & delay2[3] & delay2[2] & delay2[1] & delay2[0];

always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1])
    if (countsec == 8'b00111011) countsec <= 8'b0;
    else  countsec <= countsec + 8'b1;

assign segsec = (countsec == 8'h0 ) ? 16'b01111110111111:
    (countsec == 8'h1) ? 16'b01111110000110: //1        0000110     0111111
    (countsec == 8'h2) ? 16'b01111111011011: //2        1011011
    (countsec == 8'h3) ? 16'b01111111001111: //3        1001111
    (countsec == 8'h4) ? 16'b01111111100110: //4        1100110
    (countsec == 8'h5) ? 16'b01111111101101: //5        1101101
    (countsec == 8'h6) ? 16'b01111111111101: //6        1111101
    (countsec == 8'h7) ? 16'b01111110000111: //7        0000111
    (countsec == 8'h8) ? 16'b01111111111111: //8        1111111
    (countsec == 8'h9) ? 16'b01111111101111: //9        1101111
    (countsec == 8'ha) ? 16'b00001100111111: //10
    (countsec == 8'hb) ? 16'b00001100000110://11
    (countsec == 8'hc) ? 16'b00001101011011://12
    (countsec == 8'hd) ? 16'b00001101001111://13
    (countsec == 8'he) ? 16'b00001101100110: //14
    (countsec == 8'hf) ? 16'b00001101101101: //15
    (countsec == 8'h10) ? 16'b00001101111101://16
    (countsec == 8'h11) ? 16'b00001100000111://17
    (countsec == 8'h12) ? 16'b00001101111111://18
    (countsec == 8'h13) ? 16'b00001101101111://19
    (countsec == 8'h14) ? 16'b10110110111111://20
    (countsec == 8'h15) ? 16'b10110110000110://21
    (countsec == 8'h16) ? 16'b10110111011011://22
    (countsec == 8'h17) ? 16'b10110111001111://23
    (countsec == 8'h18) ? 16'b10110111100110://24
    (countsec == 8'h19) ? 16'b10110111101101://25
    (countsec == 8'h1a) ? 16'b10110111111101://26
    (countsec == 8'h1b) ? 16'b10110110000111://27
    (countsec == 8'h1c) ? 16'b10110111111111://28
    (countsec == 8'h1d) ? 16'b10110111101111://29
    (countsec == 8'h1e) ? 16'b10011110111111://30
    (countsec == 8'h1f) ? 16'b10011110000110://31
    (countsec == 8'h20) ? 16'b10011111011011://32
    (countsec == 8'h21) ? 16'b10011111001111://33
    (countsec == 8'h22) ? 16'b10011111100110://34
    (countsec == 8'h23) ? 16'b10011111101101://35
    (countsec == 8'h24) ? 16'b10011111111101://36
    (countsec == 8'h25) ? 16'b10011110000111://37
    (countsec == 8'h26) ? 16'b10011111111111://38
    (countsec == 8'h27) ? 16'b10011111101111://39
    (countsec == 8'h28) ? 16'b11001100111111://40
    (countsec == 8'h29) ? 16'b11001100000110://41
    (countsec == 8'h2a) ? 16'b11001101011011://42
    (countsec == 8'h2b) ? 16'b11001101001111://43
    (countsec == 8'h2c) ? 16'b11001101100110://44
    (countsec == 8'h2d) ? 16'b11001101101101://45
    (countsec == 8'h2e) ? 16'b11001101111101://46
    (countsec == 8'h2f) ? 16'b11001100000111://47
    (countsec == 8'h30) ? 16'b11001101111111://48
    (countsec == 8'h31) ? 16'b11001101101111://49
    (countsec == 8'h32) ? 16'b11011010111111://50
    (countsec == 8'h33) ? 16'b11011010000110://51
    (countsec == 8'h34) ? 16'b11011011011011://52
    (countsec == 8'h35) ? 16'b11011011001111://53
    (countsec == 8'h36) ? 16'b11011011100110://54
    (countsec == 8'h37) ? 16'b11011011101101://55
    (countsec == 8'h38) ? 16'b11011011111101://56
    (countsec == 8'h39) ? 16'b11011010000111://57
    (countsec == 8'h3a) ? 16'b11011011111111://58
    (countsec == 8'h3b) ? 16'b11011011101111://59
    16'b01111110111111;

always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1] or posedge outm)
if (outm)
    countmin <= countmin + 8'b1;
   else if (countmin == 8'b00111011 && countsec == 8'b00111011) countmin <= 8'b0;
    else if (countmin != 00111011 && countsec == 8'b00111011) countmin <= countmin + 8'b1;
    else countmin <= countmin;

assign segmin = (countmin == 8'h0) ? 16'b01111110111111:
    (countmin == 8'h1) ? 16'b01111110000110: //1        0000110     0111111
    (countmin == 8'h2) ? 16'b01111111011011: //2        1011011
    (countmin == 8'h3) ? 16'b01111111001111: //3        1001111
    (countmin == 8'h4) ? 16'b01111111100110: //4        1100110
    (countmin == 8'h5) ? 16'b01111111101101: //5        1101101
    (countmin == 8'h6) ? 16'b01111111111101: //6        1111101
    (countmin == 8'h7) ? 16'b01111110000111: //7        0000111
    (countmin == 8'h8) ? 16'b01111111111111: //8        1111111
    (countmin == 8'h9) ? 16'b01111111101111: //9        1101111
    (countmin == 8'ha) ? 16'b00001100111111: //10
    (countmin == 8'hb) ? 16'b00001100000110: //11
    (countmin == 8'hc) ? 16'b00001101011011: //12
    (countmin == 8'hd) ? 16'b00001101001111: //13
    (countmin == 8'he) ? 16'b00001101100110: //14
    (countmin == 8'hf) ? 16'b00001101101101: //15
    (countmin == 8'h10) ? 16'b00001101111101://16
    (countmin == 8'h11) ? 16'b00001100000111://17
    (countmin == 8'h12) ? 16'b00001101111111://18
    (countmin == 8'h13) ? 16'b00001101101111://19
    (countmin == 8'h14) ? 16'b10110110111111://20
    (countmin == 8'h15) ? 16'b10110110000110://21
    (countmin == 8'h16) ? 16'b10110111011011://22
    (countmin == 8'h17) ? 16'b10110111001111://23
    (countmin == 8'h18) ? 16'b10110111100110://24
    (countmin == 8'h19) ? 16'b10110111101101://25
    (countmin == 8'h1a) ? 16'b10110111111101://26
    (countmin == 8'h1b) ? 16'b10110110000111://27
    (countmin == 8'h1c) ? 16'b10110111111111://28
    (countmin == 8'h1d) ? 16'b10110111101111://29
    (countmin == 8'h1e) ? 16'b10011110111111://30
    (countmin == 8'h1f) ? 16'b10011110000110://31
    (countmin == 8'h20) ? 16'b10011111011011://32
    (countmin == 8'h21) ? 16'b10011111001111://33
    (countmin == 8'h22) ? 16'b10011111100110://34
    (countmin == 8'h23) ? 16'b10011111101101://35
    (countmin == 8'h24) ? 16'b10011111111101://36
    (countmin == 8'h25) ? 16'b10011110000111://37
    (countmin == 8'h26) ? 16'b10011111111111://38
    (countmin == 8'h27) ? 16'b10011111101111://39
    (countmin == 8'h28) ? 16'b11001100111111://40
    (countmin == 8'h29) ? 16'b11001100000110://41
    (countmin == 8'h2a) ? 16'b11001101011011://42
    (countmin == 8'h2b) ? 16'b11001101001111://43
    (countmin == 8'h2c) ? 16'b11001101100110://44
    (countmin == 8'h2d) ? 16'b11001101101101://45
    (countmin == 8'h2e) ? 16'b11001101111101://46
    (countmin == 8'h2f) ? 16'b11001100000111://47
    (countmin == 8'h30) ? 16'b11001101111111://48
    (countmin == 8'h31) ? 16'b11001101101111://49
    (countmin == 8'h32) ? 16'b11011010111111://50
    (countmin == 8'h33) ? 16'b11011010000110://51
    (countmin == 8'h34) ? 16'b11011011011011://52
    (countmin == 8'h35) ? 16'b11011011001111://53
    (countmin == 8'h36) ? 16'b11011011100110://54
    (countmin == 8'h37) ? 16'b11011011101101://55
    (countmin == 8'h38) ? 16'b11011011111101://56
    (countmin == 8'h39) ? 16'b11011010000111://57
    (countmin == 8'h3a) ? 16'b11011011111111://58
    (countmin == 8'h3b) ? 16'b11011011101111://59
    16'b11011010111111;

always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1] or posedge outh)
    if (outh) begin
        counthr <= counthr + 8'b1;
        end
    else if(counthr != 8'b00001100 && countmin == 8'b00111011 && countsec == 8'b00111011) counthr <= counthr + 8'b1;
    else if (counthr == 8'b00001100 && countmin == 8'b00111011 && countsec == 8'b00111011 ) counthr <= 8'b1;
    else  counthr <= counthr;

assign seghr = (counthr == 8'h1) ? 16'b01111110000110: //1      0000110     0111111
    (counthr == 8'h2) ? 16'b01111111011011: //2     1011011
    (counthr == 8'h3) ? 16'b01111111001111: //3     1001111
    (counthr == 8'h4) ? 16'b01111111100110: //4     1100110
    (counthr == 8'h5) ? 16'b01111111101101: //5     1101101
    (counthr == 8'h6) ? 16'b01111111111101: //6     1111101
    (counthr == 8'h7) ? 16'b01111110000111: //7     0000111
    (counthr == 8'h8) ? 16'b01111111111111: //8     1111111
    (counthr == 8'h9) ? 16'b01111111101111: //9     1101111
    (counthr == 8'ha) ? 16'b00001100111111: //10
    (counthr == 8'hb) ? 16'b00001100000110: //11
    (counthr == 8'hc) ? 16'b00001101011011: //12
    16'b01111110000110;
endmodule
```

Comment: This line `always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1] or posedge outm)` is legal Verilog, but  won't synthesise. Think about it: what hardware can you design which is sensitive to both a clock edge and an edge on some other signal? If you want to detect an edge on any other signal, you need to design a [_synchronous edge detector_](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/synchronisation/) (a link to my company's website).

Answer (score 2):

Your design is not synchronous with [multiple clocks domains](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/its/bluespec/training/BSV/slides/Lec10_Multiple_Clocks.pdf) (clk, slow_clk2[M-1] and slow_clk[N-1]). I think you don't want to manage [clock domains crossing](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2008Boston_CDC.pdf) in your design. Am I wrong ?

All processes in your design (always @) should toggle with clk signal. 
To solve your problem you should detect the rising edge of slow_clk2[M-1] and slow_clk[M-1] as following

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    if(slow_clk2_old != slow_clk2[M-1] and slow_clk2[M-1] == 1'b1)
        slow_clk2_rise <= 1'b1;
    else
        slow_clk2_rise <= 1'b0;

    slow_clk2_old <= slow_clk2[M-1]
end
```

And use your signal slow_clk2_rise like it (instead of posedge ...):

```
always @ (posedge clk)  // all your synchronous process must toggle on clk
begin
if (slow_clk2_rise)
    begin
        delay <= delay << 1;    
        delay2 <= delay2 << 1;
        delay[0] <= ~minbtn;
        delay2[0] <= ~hrbtn;
    end
end
```

Do the same with slow_clk[M-1]